# Shopify Product Data

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm trying to add the product url and image to a div within a slider.  However, I added the product dropdown to the schema, but it isn't pulling the data to the div.  Please find the schema below:

```
{% schema %}
{
"name": "Product-Slideshow",
  "settings": [
{
  "id": "text-box",
  "type": "text",
  "label": "Heading",
  "default": "Title"
}
],
"blocks": [
{
  "type": "select",
  "name": "Add Product",
  "settings": [
    {
    "type":      "product",
    "id":        "id",
    "url":       "url",
    "label":     "text",
    "info":      "text"
    },
  ]
}
],
"presets": [
{
  "name": "Product-Slideshow",
  "category": "Image",
  "blocks": [
    { 
      "type": "select"
    },
    {
      "type": "select"
    }
  ]
 }
]
}
{% endschema %}
```

Here is the div it is to be placed in.

```
<div class="owl-carousel">
{% for block in section.blocks %}  
<div><a href="{{ product.url }}" class="btn"><img src="{{ image.src | 
product_img_url }}"></a></div> 
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It could be that you're block is just saving the product handle, not the entire product object. In your block, could you add a `{{ product | json }}` somewhere visible to see what you're getting?  If you're just getting the product handle, you just need to add a `{% assign section_product = all_products[product] %}`at the beginning of your `for` loop, then use the assigned variable instead of `product` inside your HTML code.

Answer (score 1):

You must call your block settings as explained here :
https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects/block#block-settings

For example, something like {{ block.settings.image }}